# Correctly initializing static array of objects without encountering initialization order fiasco using object references

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, static-order-fiasco

I'm trying to implement a lightweight map by simply using an array of elements whose members are a key and a value. The map contents are known at compile-time so I think of using a fixed-size array as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

// class Item is declared in file1.h. Definition could be in file1.cpp.
class Item
{
public:
    Item(const std::string name) : m_name(name) {}
    const std::string GetName() const { return m_name; }

private:
    const std::string m_name;
};

// The static consts are declared in file2.h which includes file1.h.
static const Item ITEM1 = std::string("Item1");
static const Item ITEM2 = std::string("Item2");
static const Item ITEM3 = std::string("Item3");
static const Item ITEM4 = std::string("Item4");

// ItemMapEntry and ItemMapUser is defined in file3.h...
struct ItemMapEntry
{
    const Item& key;
    const Item& value;
};

class ItemMapUser
{
public:
    void Run();

private:
    static const ItemMapEntry map[];
};

// and declared in file3.cpp which includes file2.h.
const ItemMapEntry ItemMapUser::map[] =
{
    { ITEM1, ITEM2 },
    { ITEM3, ITEM4 }
};

void ItemMapUser::Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(map) / sizeof(map[0])); i++)
    {
        printf("%s        %s\n", map[i].key.GetName().c_str(), map[i].value.GetName().c_str());
    }
}

// main.cpp includes file3.h.
int main()
{
    ItemMapUser itemMapUser;
    itemMapUser.Run();
}
```

Now to my question: The code snippet works as intended but I somehow have the feeling that I'm relying on the initialization order to have the ITEM1 to ITEM4 having their content initialized before using them in the ItemMapUser::map. I searched through the many questions referring to this topic (especially those with the static-order-fiasco tag) but couldn't find any one related to the use of arrays.

- May I encounter the initialization order fiasco?
- If no, what prevents it from happening here?
- Does it matter that I'm using an array? How would it look like if I tried to initialize a simple variable using `const Item anotherItem = ITEM1;` for example?

Comment: Also see [AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `ItemMapUser::map` in code which can be called from
the constructor of a static object?  There's no problem 
initializing the references with unconstructed objects, but
there will be if you use them before the object is constructed.

Re your questions:

1. Not unless you actually use the objects the references
   designate in the constructor of a static object.
2. Basically, the fact that these are references, and you can
   safely initialize a referene with an unconstructed object.
   (There are certain restrictions when inheritance is involved,
   but they don't seem to be relevant here.)
3. It has nothing to do with whether you're initializing an
   object or an array.  If you're initialization an *object*
   (member of an array or not) rather than a reference, and calling
   the copy constructor, the object being copied had better be
   constructed.  Which you can only guarantee if it is defined in
   the same translation unit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got the habit of using references wherever I don't need something else and this is obviously a good habit in this case (and in many others...). Would you mind providing a further explanation to the restrictions when inheritance is involved?

Comment: @RolandSarrazin If the actual objects are `Derived`, and the
reference is to a `Base`, the conversion `Derived&` to `Base&`
is undefined behavior until the object being referenced has been
constructed; see §3.8/5.  (In practice, it will work until virtual
inheritance is involved, and depending on the compiler, it might
work even with virtual inheritance.  But it doesn't have to, and
I've been hit by it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes you may encounter the static initialization order fiasco.

The reason you have not encountered it yet is that the application has not yet got complicated enough to create a circular static initialization.

I don't think using an array makes any difference.

At any rate it isn't a risk worth taking. I would start with the following pattern and evolve it as required, i.e. creating a static class or whatever best suits your purpose.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


// Define safely in any module and use safely from any module.
// With C++11 use of an initializer list could eliminate the init statement.
// If you want to define the constants separately from the map use of constexpr
// should preclude any initialization order issues.
static const map<string, string>& Map()
{
   static map<string, string> map;
   static bool init = false;

   if(!init)
   {
      map["Item1"] = "Item2";
      map["Item3"] = "Item4";
      init = true;
   }

   return map;
}


int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world!";
}
```

Comment: I don't intend to use maps as 1) the number of entries will definitely not become huge and 2) we don't use any construct that will use dynamic memory. As the construction of references is not dangerous and the map will never be used in any constructor (per coding rules) I'll stick to my solution which was confirmed by the accepted answer. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question was simplified in the course of asking, but there's an awful lot of thrashing going on here for something that's basically much simpler.

```
struct entry {
    const char *key;
    const char *value;
};

entry data_map[] = {
    "Item1", "Item2",
    "Item3", "Item4",
    0,       0
};

for (entry *current = data_map; current->key != 0; ++current)
    printf("%s %s\n", current->key, current->value);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for optimization but my goal was to write a compiling and running snippet out of our software structure which is much more complex. The code comments regarding the different included files reflect the actual structure.